# Windows CMD - Setar String com Acentuação

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Estou tentando criar uma Batch (CMD) no Windows que "varra" pastas em um determinado diretório e em seguida renomeie as sub-pastas de acordo com um critério que eu definir.

Estou usando o código abaixo para realizar a operação (detalhe: esse código eu encontrei na internet e fiz alguns ajustes pequenos).

```
    FOR /D %%D IN (C:\Users\meuUsuario\Desktop\Music\*) DO CALL :RENAME "%%D"
pause

:RENAME
SET CRITERIA=\"(Músicas)"
FOR /D %%R IN (%1%CRITERIA%) DO RENAME %%R "(Singles)"
```

Se eu mudo o meu critério para alguma pasta que a nomenclatura não tenha acentuação, funciona normalmente.

Estou a um tempinho conseguindo resolver isso, mas tá difícil...

Comment: Edite o script no próprio CMD. Provavelmente você está salvando o arquivo no encoding errado. Dê um `type meuarquivo.bat` e veja se está aparecendo certo para conferir se o acento está correto no CMD.

Comment: @Bacco Entendi sim e faz sentido. Eu fiz o "type" e a acentuação apareceu "bugada" realmente... Como faço para editar o script ou criar um pelo CMD ao invés do Notepad? Edit "minhaBat.bat" não funcionou...

Comment: Não tem um editor de código aí? Vários deles permitem escolher o encoding na hora de salvar. Você poderia usar um `copy con arquivo.bat` e digitar no proprio console, mas fica infernal corrigir erros de digitação :)

Comment: @Bacco Eu criei o script pelo notepad++ (selecionando a linguagem Batch). Tentei criar também pelo notepad e salvei em 3 timos diferentes de enconding. Todos os acentos ficaram bugados.

Comment: tente usar o encoding `Character Sets > Western European > OEM 850` do NP++ - Pra saber qual é o encoding correto, entre no CMD e digite `chcp` [enter]

Comment: @Bacco Resolveu! Era isso mesmo! 850. Salvei pelo NP++ e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O provável problema é que ao salvar o arquivo, não foi escolhido o encoding correto.

O primeiro passo é saber o *encoding* correto, digitando o comando `chcp` no console:

[image: chcp]

Em boa parte dos sistemas, o retorno vai ser 850. A solução é usar um editor de código que permita salvar no Codepage correto.

Como você mencionou que tem o Notepad++, esta opção se encontra no menu

[image: Encoding > Character sets > Western European > OEM 850]

(se não for a 850, precisa localizar a opção mais adequada no menu)

Um bom tira-teima pra ver se o arquivo ficou em ordem depois da edição, é no próprio CMD executar:

```
type arquivo.bat
```

e verificar se os caracteres acentuados aparecem corretamente.

<sub><sup>Basicamente formalizei como resposta os passos que foram indicados em comentários separados, para eventualmente ajudar alguém com problema similar</sup></sub>

Comment: Perfeita a explicação! Parabéns!

Comment: Eu realmente não sabia sobre o encoding, isso me ajudou muito ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento só pra constar, chcp 65001 muda o console pra UTF-8, mas aí pode bagunçar a saída de outras aplicações,

Comment: @Bacco é coisa simples, são apenas uns menus por "choose", tenho um ambiente e inglês e outro em português, vou testar ambos e ver as variações. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o @Bacco disse, pode ser problema com o encoding. Um tempo atrás eu tive esse problema, que ainda gerava novos `.bat` apartir de outro `.bat`, para resolver troquei para *Windows-1252*, adicionando o comando abaixo na primeira linha:

```
chcp 1252
```

Ou para converter:

```
CMD / U / C type ascii.txt > unicode.txt
```

Comment: Tentei o chcp e ele afirmou ter mudado o enconding mas continuou com o problema de acentuação. Ainda exibiu a mensagem mais ou menos assim: "P#gina de c%digo ativada 1252", rsrs... O comando "CMD / U / C ..." eu executei e ele criou outro arquivo. Porém o mesmo não foi possível de ser executado, pois ele gerou erro no "F" do "FOR" (instrução do script).

Comment: @AntônioFilho Tente sem espaço e com aspas no comando (**`/c`**) invocado pelo cmd: **`CMD/U/S/C "type ascii.txt>unicode.txt"`**