# Como fazer para imprimir palavras com caracteres especiais em linguagem c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char palavra[10];
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese_Brazil");
    printf("açúcar\n");
    gets( palavra);
    printf("a palavra digitada foi: %s", palavra);
    
    return(0);
}
```

[image: primeira saída com esse código][image: saída utilizando setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.UTF-8");]

Comment: no primeiro printf a palavra açúcar é imprimida corretamente na tela, usando a função setlocale, mas se no gets eu escrevo "açúcar" , por exemplo, da erro ao imprimir na tela no segundo printf. Quando testo com palavras comuns funciona, mas se o usuário insere uma palavra com caracteres especiais da erro no texto. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Nunca use `gets()`, por motivo algum, mesmo em exercícios. `gets()` foi descontinuado no C99 e removido da biblioteca padrão completamente no C2011 porque era uma grande [falha de segurança](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados). Use  [`fgets()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Ex: `fgets(palavra, sizeof(palavra), stdin);`

Comment: O código está bom. Eu testo aqui no meu pc e funciona tudo correto. Tanto o printf com `açúcar` funciona bem, assim como o que é lido, quer seja com `gets` ou `fgets` ainda que como já foi dito, não deve usar `gets`. Um [pequeno video para exemplificar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGisg.gif)

Comment: Por que será que não funciona no meu? Eu tentei no dev c++ e no visual Studio code

Comment: Mostra para gente o que está retornando, para que possamos o orientar. Não se preocupe se pergunta for fechada, os comentários continuam abertos.

Comment: Então, a saída que eu tenho é apenas o primeiro açúcar impresso corretamente na tela, no segundo da erro, isso utilizando o código exatamente como está postado aqui. Agora se eu coloco setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.UTF-8"); aí inverte, o primeiro açúcar da erro e o segundo aparece corretamente.

Comment: Tira um print pois temos que ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: primeira saída: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX5FB.jpg , utilizando UTF-8 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/swsWx.jpg

Comment: Você está executando no CMD, né? Tenta executar o código no powershell. É uma pergunta em java mas veja se ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168103/como-apresentar-a-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta-no-retorno-do-cmd veja essa também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142618/windows-cmd-setar-string-com-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o e veja a função específica do windows [SetConsoleOutputCP()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp)

Answer (score 0):

Substitua a função `gets` por `fgets`. A função `gets()` é instável, pode gerar problemas. Não recomendo usar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char palavra[10];
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese_Brazil");
    printf("açúcar\n");
    fgets(palavra,10,stdin);
    printf("a palavra digitada foi: %s", palavra);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica, não sabia como usar essa função "fgets"; mas e pra fazer com que a palavra digitada sai com pontuação? eu pesquisei um pouco e usei setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.UTF-8"); ela faz com que a palavra inserida na variável "palavra" saia correta se estiver caracter especial, mas no primeiro printf("açúcar"); da erro, estou tentando achar uma solução para os dois saírem corretos.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que possivelmente essa dúvida ou já foi resolvida ou foi deixada de lado. Mas para aqueles que tentaram de tudo e nada funcionou, eu tenho uma outra solução que eu encontrei para contornar esse problema tão chatinho, bom vamos lá.

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

wchar_t nome[50];
wprintf(L"Insira seu nome: ");
wscanf(L"%ls", nome);

int idade;
wprintf(L"Insira a sua idade: ");
wscanf(L"%d", &idade);

wprintf(L"Nome: %ls\nIdade: %d\n", nome, idade);
wprintf(L"--------------------------------------\n");
wprintf(L"Olá %ls , agora você pode ver caracteres especiais como: $@ e também acentos!\n");
wprintf(L"--------------------------------------");

return 0;
```

}

Desta forma funcionou para meu código, eu uso o VS Code.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).